# Same resource being loaded over and over?

Tags: wordpress, loading

I was looking under the 'network' tab in developer tools to check which resources are taking the longest to load, and I noticed the same video being loaded multiple times?

How do I prevent this from occurring? It is being loaded in Wordpress.

Please see the screenshot...

[image: screenshot showing same resource being loaded multiple times]